# Show/Hide div with JQuery depending on Dropdown list selected value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have read existing questions however they do not seem to resolve my problem.
I would like to be able to hide the div "answer_wrapper" when the option "Open Ended" is selected for the drop down list.

I have written some code, however when I run the solution nothing appears to happen when selecting the "Open Ended" option in the drop down list.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$(function () 
{
    $("#QuestnType").change(function () 
    {
        ToggleDropdown();
    });
    ToggleDropdown(); 
});
function ToggleDropdown() 
{
    if ($("#QuestnType").val() == "Open Ended") 
    {
        $("#answer_wrapper").hide();
    }
    else 
    {
        $("#answer_wrapper").show();
    }
 };
```

The drop down list

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="QuestnType" CssClass="form">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Check Boxes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Drop Down</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Open Ended</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Radio Buttons</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<div id="answer_wrapper">
    some code here
</div>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Open Ended" is the text, the value value is 3

```
if ($("#QuestnType").val() == 3) ...
```

or

```
if ($("#QuestnType").text() == "Open Ended") ...
```

one other thing to note is that Server Ids != client Ids. if the drop down exists within another server control the client id becomes an ugly auto-generated webforms client id. either inject the client id into the jquery selector or use a unique class name to select the control.

Comment: then you val() and check for 3

Comment: Add you said the master page was changing the id of the drop down list. I assigned a class name to the drop down and it works perfectly now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$("#QuestnType").val() gives the value of the dropdown option (3, in this case).

You should either test for $("#QuestnType").val() === "3" (preferable) or $("#QuestnType").text() === "Open Ended".

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because $("#QuestnType").val() pulls the value from the `value` attribute. Just change it to `if ($("#QuestnType").val() == 3)` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon Jason's answer, you can use the following to ensure that your javascript will reference the correct id of the server control, even if it's contained in another server control:

```
$(function () 
{
    $("#<%=QuestnType.ClientID%>").change(function () 
    {
        ToggleDropdown();
    });
    ToggleDropdown(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're guaranteed that your control IDs won't change (due to a master page prefixing them), then this type of approach in this fiddle can help:

http://jsfiddle.net/dhoerster/MZKBJ/1/

Essentially, here's what the javascript looks like:

```
$(function () 
{
    $("#QuestnType").change(function () 
    {
        ToggleDropdown();
    });
    ToggleDropdown(); 
});
function ToggleDropdown() 
{

    if ($("#QuestnType").val() === "3") 
    {
        alert($('#QuestnType').val());
        $("#answer_wrapper").hide();
    }
    else 
    {
        alert($('#QuestnType').val());
        $("#answer_wrapper").show();
    }
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the ID you are using in your JS will be different from the one generated by asp.net. You should set the ClientIdMode="Static" to make sure that "QuestnType" is the ID rendered to the page.